# How to escape encoding within a globalized string without raw?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, globalize

I use the rails Gem Globalize to translate my strings. When I display the strings I have an encoding error when displaying special characters like `' : =`

For the apostrophe `'` the encoding is & #39;

This encoding error disappear if i use the raw => `raw my_string_with_enconding`

How could I escape this encoding error without the raw ?

I have included the `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in my header

Comment: `&#39;` _is_ the correct encoding for `'` in HTML. Maybe your string gets encoded twice. Could you show a more complete example? How does your string look like (content-wise) and how do you output your string in your view?

Comment: Here is an example https://www.topparrain.com/fr/ads/4154
The title is output like this
````<%= @ad.title %>````
The content of the string is within the globalize table and I'm not sure how to access it

Comment: When I switch to the localized language Fr and run ``Ad.find(4154).title`` I get 
``"OBTENEZ 15 € D&#39;ARGENT GRATUIT !!!!" ``

Comment: And what's the (unaltered) value of `Ad.find(4154).title`? What's stored in the database table?

Comment: That's what I get directly from the database when I run rails command.

Comment: That means your database contains encoded HTML entities. Don’t do that – store the actual text instead. Rails will encode it as needed.

Comment: Ok so the error is coming form the string I get from Google Translate API ````translate = Google::Cloud::Translate.new version: :v2, project_id: "..."
name_translation = translate.translate "doesn't like", to: "fr"
puts name_translation```` The result output this ````n&#39;aime pas````. How could I convert that back to text before storing this string in my database? Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: Suceeded !! The I converted the google translated string with ````CGI.unescapeHTML(my_string)````. Error was not coming from the Gem globalize but from the way I received and stored the google translated datas. Thanks for your help !!